# check if a cell having multiple numbers contain a specific value

Tags: excel

```
I have a column A with the values
```

```
Col A

A1   1:2:3:3
A2   2:3:4:5
A3   1:04:05
```

In excel from ColumnA I have to check among the cells A1, A2, A3 if any of the cell contains the number 5 or 05. If true it has to return true. How to get the formula in excel for the above mentioned condition? I tried with Search("5", A1) but it doesn't work?

What formula can be used please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these:

[image]

The "*" is the wildcard...

Or :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Excel 2013** or later version, you can use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FILTERXML("<b><a>["&SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","]</a><a>[")&"]</a></b>","//a")={"[5]","[05]"}))>0
```

Drag it down to apply across.

> The logic is to use **SUBSTITUTE** function to convert each string into a valid `xml` script, such as `"<b><a>[1]</a><a>[2]</a><a>[3]</a><a>[3]</a></b>"` for `1:2:3:3`,
>
> then use **FILTERXML** function to convert the string into a range of values separated by the `:` colon sign, such as `{"[1]";"[2]";"[3]";"[3]"}`. I have added special symbols `[` and `]` for each value within the range for exact match purpose,
>
> lastly compare the the range with `{"[5]","[05]"}` and use **SUMPRODUCT** to find out if there is at least one match or `TRUE` from the comparison. If `>0` i.e. at least one match is found, returns `TRUE`, otherwise `FALSE`.

---

**EDIT #2**

If you do not have access to **FILTERXML** function, you can also try the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(FIND({"[5]","[05]"},"["&SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","][")&"]"),0))>0
```

> The logic is similar, firstly use **SUBSTITUTE** function to convert the string `1:2:3:3` into `"[1][2][3][3]"`, then use **FIND** function to find out if the string contains any of the following `{"[5]","[05]"}`, and lastly use **SUMPRODUCT** function to return the result, if `>0` then `TRUE` else `FALSE`.

Let me know if you have any questions. Here are the strings I have tested:

```
| Strings            | Result |
|--------------------|--------|
| 1:2:3:3            | FALSE  |
| 2:3:4:5            | TRUE   |
| 1:04:05            | TRUE   |
| 005:50:15:25:55    | FALSE  |
| 505:550:500:05a:O5 | FALSE  |
```

Answer (score 1):

To see if **5** exists in the set of cells, use:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(":5:",";" & TEXTJOIN(":",TRUE,A1:A3) & ":"))
```

This will find **5**, but avoid stuff like **55**.

[image]

To check for **05**, make the obvious substitution in the formula.

**EDIT#1:**

To test a **single cell**, use:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(":" & "5" & ":",":" & A2 & ":"))
```

[image]

Comment: the first cell doesn't contain 5 yet its showing true instead of evaluating to false.

Comment: @user2109946  Your question was if **ANY** of the cells contained the value, not just a single cell. So if the value **5** or **05** appears anywhere in the column, *True* is returned.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Gary. Thank you for the formula though. I tried modifying your formula =ISNUMBER(SEARCH(":5:",";" & TEXTJOIN(":",TRUE,A1) & ":")) but it was not evaluating properly

Comment: @user2109946  See my **EDIT#1**